# Promql use metric value as a new label

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-alertmanager

I have this metric: `task_code{pod="foobar"} 9`

I am trying to write an expression to check the value of the mentioned metric to raise an alert as the value of the above metric can be any number.

I can do the following but the values to be matched are plenty.

```
(task_code{pod="foobar"} == 9 or task_code{pod="foobar"} == 15 or task_code{pod="foobar"} == 29)
```

But looks like regex can only be applied on a label value and Not on a metric value.

I tried exploring the `label_replace` function to create a new label out of the metric value but no go.

Looking to have something like

```
task_code{pod="foobar"} in [9,15,29]
```

or

```
task_code{pod="foobar"} =~ "(9|15|29)"
```

Any pointer is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your metric is an anti-pattern and, rather than try to force Prometheus into this somewhat unnatural behavior, you should reconsider the metric (if possible).

Measurements (counters, gauges) etc. should be continuous.

Corollary: measurements that are discrete values (and I think `code` is a smell here) should be label values.

Unless you can correct the metric, you're limited to PromQL [Operators](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/) and I suspect you'll be limited to enumerating the many conditions:

`task_code{foo="..."}=={value} or ...`

Comment: Respectfully, I disagree with stance of this answer. `code` are acceptable, take `probe_http_status_code` of blackbox exporter as an example. Even more, if this code encodes result of something (job or request, for example) it *must* be a value and not a label: otherwise dealing with such metric will be accompanied by all sorts of problems.

Comment: I kind of agree with @markalex and also given the fact that we can't use regex on the metric value makes it difficult to deal with such cases.

Comment: If you want to continue to use the code as the metric value, then I think the only solution is to enumerate each case in query.